# Error Oracle 12c database ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation, oracle

When im trying to install "Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2.0) for ZLinux-64"  Im getting this error message, also tried to install it on ubuntu 16.10 still the same can someone help me figure out whats the problem?

```
accord@accord-aspire:~/Downloads/database$ ./runInstaller 
/home/accord/Downloads/database/install/.oui: 1: /home/accord/Downloads/database/install/.oui: ELF�%�@@@@: not found
/home/accord/Downloads/database/install/.oui: 1: /home/accord/Downloads/database/install/.oui: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

[Erorr message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/942dd.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have downloaded the wrong installer. The one you got is for a different architecture ( IBM zSystem ).

You should download the installer from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/database12c-linux-download-2240591.html).